# Converting simple impala sql query to ibis

Tags: python, python-3.x, impala, ibis

I'm trying to convert a simple Impala sql query to an ibis query in python, but I'm having trouble understanding ibis's syntax when converting from sql.

So far, I've tried this:

```
agg = joblist_table_handle.lastupdatedate.max()
joblist = joblist_table_handle.group_by('id').aggregate(agg).sort_by('lastupdatedate').execute()
```

I'm hoping to get my result close to the sql query:

```
SELECT id, max(lastupdatedate) 
FROM joblist_table
GROUP BY id
SORT BY lastupdatedate
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your aggregation (note the `last_update_date=agg` keyword argument passed to the `aggregate` call):

```
agg = joblist_table_handle.lastupdatedate.max()
joblist = joblist_table_handle.group_by('id').aggregate(last_update_date=agg).sort_by('last_update_date').execute()
```